# PowerShell keep multiple spaces

Tags: powershell

While implementing the suggestions in the topic [Drag and Drop to a Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819908/drag-and-drop-to-a-powershell-script) we discovered that PowerShell consolidates multiple spaces into one. This is blocking us from dragging and dropping files through Windows Explorer into .bat/.ps1 constructs with multiple spaces.

This can easily be verified by the following command:

```
powershell -command "& echo {"a  a"}"
```

This will result in:

`a a`

whereas the following result is expected:

`a  a`

How can this be achieved?

Please note that your provided solution must fit into the Windows Explorer drag-and-drop .bat -> .ps1 flow. Currently in the .bat file we have:
`powershell.exe -Command "& '%PSScript%' '%*'"`
which obviously results in PowerShell stripping the duplicate spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - escaping string passed to child process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276662/powershell-escaping-string-passed-to-child-process)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
powershell -command "& echo 'a  a'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check if below solves your problem.

*"Replace 10 with number of spaces you want."*

```
powershell -command '& echo {"a"' ''.padleft(10, ' ') '"a"}'
```

output:

```
a            a
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me with a simple :

```
write-host a ("    ") a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `` ` `` to escape spaces   like:

```
Write-Host "a` ` ` a"
```

Output:

```
a   a
```