# SharePoint 2010: creating a site in a sitecollection automatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010, automation, sitecollection

I am looking at ways of automating creation of sites in a site collection in SharePoint 2010. Actually, for some load/stress test, I need to create around 100 sites in a site collection. I can create a site from the SharePoint admin site. But I wish to create large number of them and possibly using some automation.

Please let me know possible ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stsadm.exe is no longer available for Sharepoint 2010

However you use [cmdlets: New-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607937.aspx)

Like: `New-spsite –url http://someWeb/sites/someSite -OwnerAlias domain\username -template STS#0`

Comment: You are right - stsadm.exe is no longer available for Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Does it support some kind of batch files?

Comment: Yes it does. Either you split your cmdlet calls by semicolon or call cmdlets from cmd line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932291/calling-powershell-cmdlets-from-windows-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

stsadm.exe is still available in SharePoint 2010.