# Batch file to set a PowerShell variable

Tags: powershell, variables, batch-file

For some reason i simply can't understand most of the sites who explain this question. So i'll try to ask here, if i'm am in the wrong place, just tell me in the comments and i'll put this in another forum and delete this question.

Let's say that i have 2 files, `Batch.bat` and `PowerShell.ps1`.

***Batch.bat:***

```
set A="ThisIsSuchVar!"
```

***PowerShell.ps1:***

```
$B = "Well, i don't know what to do here"
```

What can i do to the `B` variable be the same as the `A` variable?

Remember: I want the Batch variable to go to the PowerShell file. It's an one-way script. I want to use the built-in windows sources. And please, consider that i am a complete newbie in programming and don't speak english very well, so be the simplest possible, please.

Comment: Are you calling Powershell.ps1 from Batch.bat?

Comment: You could set an environment variable in batch to be read by PowerShell or (simpler) configure the PowerShell script to accept the batch variable as an argument. In the case of the latter you wont have to worry about cleaning up variables or session states.

Comment: Title is a little misleading but this post should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932291/calling-powershell-cmdlets-from-windows-batch-file

Comment: Related: you might be interested in playing with [Batch + PowerShell polyglots](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=45095#p45095).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your batch file `run.bat`, set the environment variable `A` and run the PowerShell script:

```
set A=8
PowerShell.exe -File .\script.ps1
pause
```

In `script.ps1`, get the environment variable `A`, and assign its value to `B`:

```
$B=$Env:A
echo $B
```

When you run `run.bat` you get:

```
C:\Temp\try>set A=8

C:\Temp\try>PowerShell.exe -File .\script.ps1
8

C:\Temp\try>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: @PetSerAI For some reason my script get stuck before the `pause`. It says the `C:\Temp\try>PowerShell.exe -File .\script.ps1
8` and simply stop. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @AdiLevin Nope, it doesn't read the `pause` line, it stops in the `C:\Temp\try>PowerShell.exe -File .\script.ps1
8`

Comment: Just stop, don't do anything else, the window stay there, the PowerShell doesn't do anything...

Comment: Ooh, sorry! Forgive me, my fault, your script is working perfectly, i just wrote it wrong.